# center image inside button

Tags: android, android-layout

i have this code for displaying an image on a button.

How to position the image so that it doesn't touch the frame/border?

this the code:

```
 <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.45"
                android:onClick="EXIT"
                android:layout_height="95dp"
                android:text="Exit"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonnew"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/zexit"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                />
```

[image]

Comment: Your question isn't too clear [to me]...

Comment: @Shaishav I've editted to what seems to make sense

Comment: need to move down a littele the arrow image to the EXIT text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are referring to the Button rather than the drawable, it would be best to use padding instead of margin, e.g. android:paddingTop